Google Sites v2 Version History - what content changed?
Using Google Sites v2 (not classic) one can see the ... Version History edit date/time/author. The only help I can find "Find what's change in a site" neglects the most important detail, finding what page content changed. It describes what I can do: name a version, make a copy of a site and revert the site or a page of the site. The left side dutifully shows the entire site as of that version. What I need is a diff - what changed for that site and page version. Each change would be good, but ideally all changes between two versions would be very helpful.

I'm amazed this is still unanswered. I suspect there are more and more people using Google Sites to create web sites. Knowing what changed is important to any group of people working together on a Google Site.
